# Create non-responsive CSS from bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

As IE <8 and some other minor browsers do not support @media queries, I'd like to create a CSS for unsupported browsers by simulating a specific width like 1200px and export it as one non-responsive CSS file to use with these browsers. Are there any tools out there or other easy ways to achieve this?

Edit: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 and media queries doesn't support - ie7. Even if you use any polyfill like Respond.js, you will be able to make IE6-8 respond to media-queries. But bootstrap-3.0 is for mobile-first design method, which doesn't support ie7. but everything should be fine if you define all your actual design outside of media queries. which will run on all browsers. If you really want to support ie7, then use bootstrap 2.*

Use conditional statements in your html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
```

and then target your browser by this:

```
.lt-ie9  .btn-nav
                {
                //for ie 8 only, change following.
                    margin: 0;
                    display: inline-block;
                }
.lt-ie8 .btn-nav{
// for ie 7
background: white;
}
```

Or just simply define your standard css which should work for all browsers at the top of the file without media queries. which should be the preferred way of writing css and with a mix of above good practise.

Or [use a polyfill like Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to make media-queries work for ie6-8

Comment: Using conditional comments to add classes for IE seems to be too much work, as I had to redefine all the styles from Bootstrap.
Aa Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first, the standard css is optimiced for small devices but stretched over the whole screen.
I've also tried respond.js and css-mediaqueries.js but both didn't work. Neither using the CSS from CDN, nor using local files.

Comment: @JohannesTrümpelmann You don't need to redefine anything. almost all css written in bootstrap is independent of other components. You must write your standard css that should run on all browsers out of media queries and then modify it under media queries down the page in css file.

Comment: @JohannesTrümpelmann check my updated answer. if you are using bootstrap 2.*, you can support ie7/8 out of the box, if using bootstrap 3.0, it doesnt support the IE7

Comment: @JohannesTrümpelmann After looking at your edited question, I have modified my answer. please read.